# Python: Reading a data file with an uneven number of columns without using PANDAS

Tags: python

I have a file formatted in general like this:

(8,9) (4,7) (9,0)

(19,125) (23,96) (256,0) (49,3)

etc.

I want to be able to get the pair in each row and column, but the number of columns in each row is arbitrary. How will I be able to do this python without using PANDAS?

Comment: read each line as a text file and parse it yourself? what have you tried already? what isn't working for you?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to be much more specific. At the simplest level, you just open the file and read each line and parse it. You might even be able to read the entire thing at once if it's small enough.

Comment: for all pairs (x,y) I have to extract the maximum y in each row.

Comment: I tried genfromtxt but its gives me an array full of 'nan'

Comment: please share the code that you tried and we can help you from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = '(19,125) (23,96) (256,0) (49,3)'
s=s.replace(')','').replace('(','')
tuples= s.split(' ')
x=[]
y=[]
for item in tuples:
        x.append(item.split(',')[0])
        y.append(item.split(',')[1])
print "max value from y :" +str(max(y))
print y
```

output

```
max value from y :96
['125', '96', '0', '3']
```